# How can I do Variable Importance Charts by the Cluster in SPSS?

Tags: statistics, cluster-analysis, spss, exploratory-data-analysis, subcommand

Does anybody know how to do Variable Importance Charts in SPSS? I want mine to look pretty much like-

https://i.stack.imgur.com/buZG3.png

Meanwhile, the best version of what I can get it to look like the output above is this- [https://imgur.com/a/ZZcXq9c](https://stackoverflow.com)

Through this subcommand-
`AIM TSC_2589 /CONTINUOUS  Age Gender EducationalLevel Occupation MontlyIncome Lifestyle_1 Lifestyle_2 Lifestyle_3 Lifestyle_4 Lifestyle_5 Lifestyle_6  Lifestyle_7 Lifestyle_8 Lifestyle_9 Lifestyle_10 Behaviours_1 Behaviours_2 Behaviours_3  Behaviours_4 Behaviours_5 Values_1 Values_2 Values_3 Values_4 Values_5 Values_6 Values_7 Values_8  Values_9 Values_10 Values_11 Values_12 Values_13 Values_14 Usage_1 Usage_2 Usage_3 Usage_4 Usage_5 /PLOT ERRORBAR IMPORTANCE(X=VARIABLE Y=TEST`

You can see that from the Variable Importance Chart = 2, some variables are recognized as Continuous with a (C) suffix. How do I solve that too? does it have anything to do with the Cluster Quality?

Appreciate all your responses!